# How to define atom for Pytables EArray creation

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

Trying to create a Pytables EArray on the run based on one column from a numpy recarray.  This seems to work if I am using createArray as I can simply pass it the numpy array extracted from the recarray.  However, for the createEArray I need to define the atom - which is causing problems

In the example MyRecArray is a recordarray with 1-D arrays for columns,  Myhdf5 is a predefined Pytables file, and Mynode is a predefined group in that file from which the EArray leaves will hang.

```
     Myfield = MyRecArray[Colname]
     afieldtype = Myfield.dtype  
     Myatom = tables.atom.Atom(afieldtype, (1,), -9999) 
     MyEarray = Myhdf5.createEArray(Mynode, Colname, Myatom, (0,))
     MyEarray.append(Myfield )          
     MyEarray.flush()
     MyEarray.close()
```

using this code give the error:

```
     NotImplementedError: ``Atom`` is an abstract class; 
     please use one of its subclasses
```

I can probably write a subroutine with case statements based on the array time and pass back an atom, but I was just wondering if there is a generic way to create such an atom by passing it the array type to be created instead of having to call a specific function for different data types, such as "tables.atom.FloatAtom(....)"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe using the function:

```
tables.Atom.from_dtype(afieldtype, dflt=-9999)
```

will allow you to create an atom without going the subroutine route. The shape is contained in the dtype "afieldtype" (eg. `dtype([('col1', '<f8', (10,))])`)